# how to add grails-support extension in sts?

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

used the springsource tool suit(STS). IDE for for develop a grails poject.i followed the instruction fron springsource.com for add a grails support extension.it's does not install. i had a message do not communicate repositary then another time i got time out message.how to add  grails support?

http://grails.org/STS+Integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are behind a firewall.  You must set your connection properties specifically through Preferences -> General -> Network Connections.

Comment: Thank you..it's working fine..turn off the firewall and AV ..then i will add extension..